Проблема при подключении питоновских библиотек
Пытаюсь подключить компоненты питона следующим образом:
if (ALPHA_USE_MATPLOTLIBCPP)
  find_package(Python3 COMPONENTS Interpreter Development REQUIRED)

  target_include_directories(alpha PUBLIC
    ${Python3_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  )

  target_link_libraries(alpha INTERFACE
    Python3::Python
    Python3::Module
  )

  target_compile_definitions(alpha PRIVATE USE_MATPLOTLIBCPP)

  find_package(Python3 COMPONENTS NumPy)

  if(Python3_NumPy_FOUND)
    target_link_libraries(alpha INTERFACE
      Python3::NumPy
    )

    target_include_directories(alpha PUBLIC
      ${Python3_NumPy_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
  message("------>> Python3_LIBRARIES = ${Python3_LIBRARIES}")
  message("------>> Python3_LIBRARY_DIRS = ${Python3_LIBRARY_DIRS}")
  message("------>> Python3_RUNTIME_LIBRARY_DIRS = ${Python3_RUNTIME_LIBRARY_DIRS}")
  else()
    target_compile_definitions(alpha INTERFACE WITHOUT_NUMPY)
  endif()
endif()

В результате переменные находятся:
[CMake] -- Found Python3: C:/Program Files/Python312/python.exe (found version "3.12.3") found components: Interpreter Development Development.Module Development.Embed 
[CMake] -- Found Python3: optimized;C:/Program Files/Python312/libs/python312.lib;debug;C:/Program Files/Python312/libs/python312_d.lib (found version "3.12.3") found components: NumPy Interpreter Development.Module 
[CMake] ------>> Python3_LIBRARIES = optimized;C:/Program Files/Python312/libs/python312.lib;debug;C:/Program Files/Python312/libs/python312_d.lib
[CMake] ------>> Python3_LIBRARY_DIRS = C:/Program Files/Python312/libs
[CMake] ------>> Python3_RUNTIME_LIBRARY_DIRS = C:/Program Files/Python312

Но при сборке ошибка:
Error   LNK1104 cannot open file 'python312.lib'
Что я упустил?

попробуйте это решение https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133698/why-does-fatal-error-lnk1104-cannot-open-file-c-program-obj-occur-when-i-c#133724

Разобрался.
Не хватало строки:
target_link_directories(alpha PUBLIC ${Python3_LIBRARY_DIRS})

